# Android: refresh image Switcher content Based on radioButton choice

Tags: java, android

My application intend to select image switcher content based on one of two selected radio button. on radio button click, the application does not choose desired option and finally the application crashed.

The big problem is i want to free the array holding images for the swicher based on the radio button checked.

Also, there are two arrays with image reference to it. i want to delete all the array inside the  gallery and add one of the reference. Here is my code.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //check which id is selected

    radioCheckedId= checkedId;


    //radio button checked

    switch(radioCheckedId){

        case R.id.radBtnAccident:
```

//delete all array
                if (pics.length>0){

```
                for (int arr=0;arr<pics.length;arr++){

                    pics[arr]=null;

                }
            }

            //populates array

            pics = new Integer[]{ R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                                  R.drawable.e,R.drawable.exit, R.drawable.plan, R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.plan };

            chooseImgArray(pics);

        break;

        case R.id.radBtnOthers:

            //populates other array

            pics = new Integer[]{R.drawable.exit, R.drawable.plan,
```

R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.plan,R.drawable.c };

```
            chooseImgArray(pics);
        break;

    default:

    break;


    }

}

public void chooseImgArray(final Integer[] array){


    iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImgSwith);

    iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in));
    iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out));

    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.galImage);

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int count,long arg3) {
            iSwitcher.setImageResource(array[count]);

        }

    });




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I put Example code for ImageSwitcher with Gallery Check it.
it is usefull to u.
```

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements ViewFactory,
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Gallery gallery;
    private ImageSwitcher iSwitcher;
    private RadioGroup rdgSelection;
    private Boolean flag = true;

    private Integer[] Array1 = { R.drawable.arrow, R.drawable.arrow1,
            R.drawable.arrow2, R.drawable.arrow3 };
    private Integer[] Array2 = { R.drawable.camera, R.drawable.camera1,
            R.drawable.camera2, R.drawable.camera3 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imgSwitcher);
        rdgSelection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgSelection);

        iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        rdgSelection.check(rdgSelection.getChildAt(
                rdgSelection.getChildCount() - 1).getId());

        if (rdgSelection.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdb1) {
            flag = true;
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(TestActivity.this));
        } else {
            flag = false;
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(TestActivity.this));
        }
        rdgSelection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(TestActivity.this));
                if (rdgSelection.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdb1)
                    flag = true;
                else
                    flag = false;
            }
        });
        gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            if (flag)
                return Array1.length;
            else
                return Array2.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            if (flag)
                i.setImageResource(Array1[position]);
            else
                i.setImageResource(Array2[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            return i;
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        if (flag)
            iSwitcher.setImageResource(Array1[position]);
        else
            iSwitcher.setImageResource(Array2[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but the application crashed

Comment: W/dalvikvm(321): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

Comment: i check above code in project its working fine their is no error. completely run project in my emulator. plz.. recheck it.

Comment: Yes Sorry Patel Deval, you are right. i misinterpreted isSwitcher = setFactory(this); but the code crash if i cliked the selected imageView onload. but thanks for all god bless you

Comment: One last thing please, do you know how to retrieve the selected ImageSwitcher Id into oncreate() please. i tried several time but it doesn't work.

Comment: u get ImageSwitcher ID or Image ID set in ImageSwitcher

Comment: Yes but i want to retrieve the id from a button. i use android.widget.ViewAnimator and getDisplayedChild() but it displays error

Comment: ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
   Integer s = i.getDisplayedChild();